# Invertir un resultado de .endsWith()

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy haciendo un ejercicio que comprueba si un NIF es correcto o no, mi duda está en la última condición del if, me gustaría saber si hay algún método o alguna forma de invertir el endsWith() y que devuelva false en caso de que sea true sin necesidad de aumentar mucho el código. Soy novato asi que perdón si es algo simple o hay algo mal.

```
String[] letras = {"T", "R", "w", "A", "G", "M", "Y", "F", "P", "D", "X", "B", "N", "J", "Z", "S", "Q", "V", "H", "L", "C", "K", "E", "T"};

    System.out.println("Introduzca su NIF: ");        
    String NIF = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    
    int n = Integer.parseInt(NIF.substring(0, NIF.length()-1));
    int resto =  n % 23;
    String letra = letras[resto];
    
    if(NIF.contains("-") || NIF.length() != 9 || NIF.endsWith(letra)){
        System.out.println("Numero no valido.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Es un NIF correcto.");
    }
```

Comment: Usando el operador lógico *not* `!NIF.endsWith(letra);`

Comment: Para invertirlo sólo tienes que usar `!`, por ejemplo: `!NIF.endsWith(letra)`

Comment: @JohnnyTB Cierto, lo probé antes pero no me iba por eso pregunté, debí de haberme confundido, Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano Cierto, lo probé antes pero no me iba por eso pregunté, debí de haberme confundido, Gracias.